# Multiple settings in Jquery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

It seems there are so many helpful topics on this matter around SO however I cannot COMBINE them all. Standalone they work well. But it's combining the functions that I'm having issues with.

What I have:

1. A 'from' and 'to' input field that uses the jquery datepicker.
2. User selects 'from' date and then the 'to' date will allow selections +4 days in the future based on the date selected. (EDITED)
3. A third, and hidden, field calculates the amount of days between the selections.

Here is a Fiddle of what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/hVnRu/

The issue:

1. If a user selects 'from' in one month and 'to' in another (ie: 08/30/2013 - 09/02/2013) then the calculated field is wrong.
2. The 'to' field is not taking the minDate 4+ days from the previously selected field into account.

And lastly, here is my code (all this is in the Fiddle above):

```
$(function () {
$("#from, #to").datepicker({
    onSelect: function () {
        var from = new Date($("#from").val().split("/").reverse().join(","));
        var to = new Date($("#to").val().split("/").reverse().join(","));
        var total = ((to - from) / 2592000000);
        var rounded = Math.round(total);
        $("#totaldays").val(rounded);

    }
});
$("#from").datepicker({
    minDate: 4,
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
$("#to").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});

});
```

A grand thanks to anyone who can help on this.

Comment: thanks @j08691 I'll remember the formatting you corrected above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after accepting my answer here is the correct version of my code.
It's basically quite simple to do what you aimed for.
If someone selects a starting date, the first possible day in the `#to` datepicker is 4 days away in the future. Therefor we use the `minDate` option and calculate the new date with `setDate`.
After a second date got selected we call the `totalDays()` function which subtracts our two dates, resulting in the difference and convert this difference into days.
If a user first selects the `#to` date we also call the `totalDays()`but to dont show negative days we check if the `#from` date is set. If not (or days is negative) don't display any  value.

```
 $(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        minDate: 4,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            //set #to date +4 days in the future, starting from #from date
            var fromDate = new Date(selectedDate);
            var minDate  = new Date(fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + 4));

            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate);
        },
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            //alternatively call it in onSelect
            totalDays();
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        minDate: 4,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            //alternatively call it in onSelect
            totalDays();
        }
    });

    function totalDays() {
        //subtract the two Date objects, convert seconds to days
        var from    = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
        var to      = $('#to').datepicker('getDate');
        var seconds = to - from;
        var days    = Math.ceil(seconds / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

        //dont fill in value if only #to has a valid
        if (days > 0 && from) {
            $('#totaldays').val(days);
        }
    }

});
```

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/zAQ2y/)

Comment: first off, thank you for this. I've played with the code in the fiddle a bit and realized that I mistakenly mislead you. The `to` date should have a `minDate` of +4 from the `from` date. Not a `maxDate` as I lead you to, sorry. I commented out the `$('#to').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', maxDate);` however it still corrects the code once you select it. What portion should I remove for alleviate that?

Comment: Here is a fiddle to expand on my comment above: http://jsfiddle.net/hVnRu/7/  If you select a range longer than 4 days, it adjusts to 4 days on its own.

Comment: I guess then comment out everything in the `onSelect` function in the `#to` datepicker. Does this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/yFVat/) suit your needs? If so I'll correct my answer.

Comment: Yes, exactly. For continuity I added `minDate: 4,` under the `#to` datepicker, so that if a user selects the `to` field first, they can't select dates differently than with the `from` field (although I guess it doesn't matter since it will get overridden after `from` is selected). Thank you very kindly for your help with this! Above and beyond with the commenting in the code, it really helps!

Comment: You're welcome! I just edited my answer with the correct solution to clear up the misunderstandings ;)